Sar-Optical image fusion
I am trying to perform image fusion of SAR-Optical data using PCA. After running the script I received an error message that say:

Fused Image: Tile error: Array: Max (NaN) cannot be less than min
(NaN).

Below is the script:
// Insert images
var sarImage = ee.Image('projects/ee-mofori3439/assets/VV_VH_Export'); // SAR image
var opticalImage = ee.Image('projects/ee-mofori3439/assets/RGB_Export'); // Optical image

// Function to check and preprocess images
var preprocessImages = function(image1, image2) {
  // Check if images are already aligned
  var areAligned = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().sample({
    region: image1.geometry(),
    scale: 10,
    projection: image1.projection(),
    geometries: true // Make sure to include geometries in the output
  }).size().eq(1).and(
    ee.Image.pixelLonLat().sample({
      region: image2.geometry(),
      scale: 10,
      projection: image2.projection(),
      geometries: true // Make sure to include geometries in the output
    }).size().eq(1)
  );

  if (!areAligned.getInfo()) {
    // Coregister the two datasets (assuming they require alignment)
    // Add your coregistration code here
    // Example: resample or warp one image to match the geometry and projection of the other
  }

  // Check spatial resolution
  var sarScale = image1.projection().nominalScale();
  var opticalScale = image2.projection().nominalScale();
  
  if (sarScale !== opticalScale) {
    // Resample images to 10m resolution
    image1 = image1.resample('bicubic').reproject({
      crs: 'EPSG:4326', // WGS 84
      scale: 10
    });
    image2 = image2.resample('bicubic').reproject({
      crs: 'EPSG:4326', // WGS 84
      scale: 10
    });
  }

  // Check projection
  var sarProjection = image1.projection().crs();
  var opticalProjection = image2.projection().crs();
  
  if (sarProjection !== opticalProjection) {
    // Reproject SAR image to match the projection of the optical image
    image1 = image1.reproject({
      crs: opticalProjection
    });
  }

  return [image1, image2];
};

// Function to compute principal components
var getPrincipalComponents = function(centered, scale, region) {
  // Collapse the bands of the image into a 1D array per pixel.
  var arrays = centered.toArray();

  // Compute the covariance of the bands within the region.
  var covar = arrays.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.centeredCovariance(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: scale,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });

  // Get the 'array' covariance result and cast to an array.
  // This represents the band-to-band covariance within the region.
  var covarArray = ee.Array(covar.get('array'));

  // Perform an eigen analysis and slice apart the values and vectors.
  var eigens = covarArray.eigen();

  // This is a P-length vector of Eigenvalues.
  var eigenValues = eigens.slice(1, 0, 1);
  // This is a PxP matrix with eigenvectors in rows.
  var eigenVectors = eigens.slice(1, 1);

  // Convert the array image to 2D arrays for matrix computations.
  var arrayImage = arrays.toArray(1);

  // Left multiply the image array by the matrix of eigenvectors.
  var principalComponents = ee.Image(eigenVectors).matrixMultiply(arrayImage);

  // Turn the square roots of the Eigenvalues into a P-band image.
  var sdImage = ee.Image(eigenValues.sqrt())
      .arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('sd')]);

  // Turn the PCs into a P-band image, normalized by SD.
  return principalComponents
      // Throw out an an unneeded dimension, [[]] -> [].
      .arrayProject([0])
      // Make the one band array image a multi-band image, [] -> image.
      .arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('pc')])
      // Normalize the PCs by their SDs.
      .divide(sdImage);
};

// Function to generate new band names
var getNewBandNames = function(prefix) {
  var sequence = ee.List.sequence(1, 10); // Change the range as needed
  return sequence.map(function(i) {
    return ee.String(prefix).cat(ee.Number(i).int());
  });
};

// Function to compute and visualize fused image
var computeAndVisualizeFusedImage = function(sarImage, opticalImage) {
  try {
    // Get the geometry (extent) of the images
    var region = ee.Geometry(sarImage.geometry()).union(opticalImage.geometry());

    // Compute mean values
    var meanSAR = sarImage.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), region, 30);
    var meanOptical = opticalImage.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), region, 30);

    // Extract mean values from dictionaries
    meanSAR = ee.Image.constant(meanSAR.values());
    meanOptical = ee.Image.constant(meanOptical.values());

    // Center the data
    var centeredSAR = sarImage.subtract(meanSAR);
    var centeredOptical = opticalImage.subtract(meanOptical);

    // Compute principal components
    var pcaSAR = getPrincipalComponents(centeredSAR, 30, region);
    var pcaOptical = getPrincipalComponents(centeredOptical, 30, region);

    // Fusion
    var fusedImage = pcaSAR.multiply(0.5).add(pcaOptical.multiply(0.5));

    // Visualize the result
    Map.addLayer(fusedImage, {}, 'Fused Image');
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle error
    print('Error occurred while computing or visualizing fused image:', error);
  }
};

// Load SAR and optical images
var sarImage = ee.Image('projects/ee-mofori3439/assets/VV_VH_Export'); // SAR image
var opticalImage = ee.Image('projects/ee-mofori3439/assets/RGB_Export'); // Optical image

// Compute and visualize fused image
computeAndVisualizeFusedImage(sarImage, opticalImage);

